# Rails: How to prevent 2 active-record attributes to be equal with validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, validation

I want to prevent users from signing up with a password = login for security reasons. I tried something like this:

```
  validates_each :password do |record, attr, value|
    if(value == self.login)
      record.errors.add(attr)
    end
  end
```

But I always get the following error: undefined method login for self. It has something to do with the class hierachy I guess, but how do I access a higher level.

I'm a little stuck here, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
if value == record.login
```

the record is passed into the block as the `record` local variable, and in this context is not `self`.